# Catch block doesn't capture the error if I upload file which not match with condition

Tags: powershell

```
   $Source='c:\uploadtool\*'  #Source Location 
    $RetailDest= "D:\ToolUpload\Retail-EIP" #1st Destination Location 
    $GroupDest= "D:\ToolUpload\Group-EIP"   #2nd Destination location
    $RetailBack="D:\ToolUpload\Retail-EIP\*"  #Backup location which copy the existing file if the file match to Retail-EIP.
    $GroupBack="D:\ToolUpload\Group-EIP\*"    # 2nd Backup location which copy the existing file if the file match to Group-EIP.
    $Backupdata="D:\Backup"   #Backup Location
    $filename = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -File -Force -Recurse
    #$logname=New-Item "D:\logs\uploadlog_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd').txt" -ItemType file -Force
    $lognamefolder="D:\logs"
    
    $logname="D:\logs\uploadlog_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd').txt"
    
    $checkLocalFolderExist = Test-Path -Path $lognamefolder
    
    $checkLocalFileExist = Test-Path -Path $logname  -PathType Leaf
     if(-NOT $checkLocalFolderExist)
    {
      New-Item -Path $lognamefolder -ItemType Directory
    }
    
    if(-NOT $checkLocalFileExist)
    {
      New-Item -Path $logname -ItemType File
    }
    
    echo "              " (Get-Date) | Add-Content -Path $logname -PassThru
    
    echo "Copying file start" |  Add-Content -Path $logname -PassThru
    
    echo "Source is:$filename" | Add-Content -Path $logname -PassThru
    
    echo  "File size = "($filename).Length  | Add-Content -Path $logname -PassThru
    
    echo "               " | Add-Content -Path $logname -PassThru
    
    $ArchiveData = New-Item -Path "$Backupdata\backup_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddHHMM')" -Force -ItemType Directory
    foreach($file in $filename)
    {
    try
    {
    if($file -match "Retail-EIP")
    {
    
     $fname=$file.fullname
     Move-Item -Path $RetailBack -Destination $ArchiveData
     echo "File has been backed up :$ArchiveData" | Add-Content -Path $logname -PassThru 
     Move-Item -Path $fname -Destination $RetailDest
     echo "File has been upload to Retail Platform: $RetailDest" |Add-Content -Path $logname -PassThru |Format-Table
     
    }
    
    if($file -match "Group-EIP")
    {
    
     $fname=$file.fullname
     Move-Item -Path $GroupBack -Destination $ArchiveData
     echo "File has been backed up :$ArchiveData" | Add-Content -Path $logname -PassThru 
     Move-Item -Path $fname -Destination $GroupDest 
     echo "File has been upload to Group Platform: $GroupDest" |Add-Content -Path $logname -PassThru | Format-Table
    }
    }
    catch  # Catch statement doesn't produce the error and capture in the log file.
    {
    Write-output "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ErrorAction Stop | Add-Content $logname -passthru
    }
    }
```

1. I am trying to copy a file from the source location and backup the existing file to a backup location,
   all set and script working as expected but few things I just want to change, like

   First, Script doesn't capture the catch statement if I upload the wrong which doesn't match with condition.
   Second, I want to capture the logs in a table format, How can I do that?

Comment: // [1] The catch never fires on basic `if` or `elsif` tests because it is designed for catching exceptions during operations that can actually throw exceptions like `Move-Item` and such. In order to have the catch working on those cmdlets, even if not terminating, you should add `-ErrorAction Stop` on them, not on a Write-Output inside the catch block itself.. // [2] `Format-Table` is for on screen table-style outputting on **objects** with properties, not for just strings.

Comment: Theo beat me to the punch. For table formatting, you can use a `[PSCustomobject]`. Also, recommend you using `$Error[0]` instead of the psitem .

Comment: @ Abraham, Could you help to show, How can I add [PSCustomobject]

Comment: In powershell `Echo` is just an alias for `Write-Output` which is writing strings. `Format-Table` is designed to format some output as a table... That works for every object with properties for example `[PSCustomObject]`s. Just doesn't make any sense for a string... (compare `$host | Format-Table` and `$host | Format-List` and `"some string" | Format-Table`)

Comment: If anyone can write one code for [PSCustomObject] for the above script, that would be helping a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented, to be able to use `try{}..catch{}`, you need to add `ErrorAction Stop` on the cmdlet(s) that actually *can* throw exceptions, like the two Move-Item cmdlets in order to also capture non-terminating exceptions.

Then you would like to get a table-style output instead of a textual log file.
In that case, you need to output **objects** with certain properties so you can then save the log file as structured CSV file (which in fact is a table) you can open in Excel.

Now, If I have this correct the code needs to:

1. Get all files from a source folder including subfolders, where the file's name contains either 'Retail-EIP' or 'Group-EIP'
2. For each of those files there is a backup destination folder defined in `$GroupDest` and `$RetailDest`
3. I in any of these backup folders, a file with that name is already present, it needs to be moved to an archive folder defined in `$ArchiveData`
4. Then the file should be moved from its source folder to the destination folder
5. You want the moves to be wrapped inside a `try{}..catch{}` structure, so any exceptions can be caught
6. A log should be maintained as structured object, so you can output as table both on screen and to file

In that case, I would change (quite a bit) of your code:

```
$Source      = 'C:\uploadtool'               # Source Location
$RetailDest  = 'D:\ToolUpload\Retail-EIP'    # 1st Destination Location
$GroupDest   = 'D:\ToolUpload\Group-EIP'     # 2nd Destination location
$ArchiveData = 'D:\Backup\backup_{0:yyyyMMddHHmm}' -f (Get-Date)
$LogFolder   = 'D:\logs'
# because of your wish to get a Table-style log, use CSV format you can open in Excel
$LogFile     = 'D:\logs\uploadlog_{0:yyyyMMdd}.csv'-f (Get-Date)

# make sure the output LogFolder exist
# by adding the -Force switch there is no need to use Test-Path first, because if
# the folder already exists, the cmdlet will return the DirectoryInfo of that,
# otherwise it will create a new folder. Since we dont want output, we use $null = ..
$null = New-Item -Path $LogFolder -ItemType Directory -Force

# loop through the files in the source folder and collect the outputted objects
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Include '*Group-EIP*', '*Retail-EIP*' -File -Force -Recurse | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Processing file '$($_.FullName)'"
        # create an object with (for now) 3 empty properties
        $out = $_ | Select-Object @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {(Get-Date)}},
                                  @{Name = 'Source'; Expression = {$_.FullName}},
                                  @{Name = 'FileSize'; Expression = {$_.Length}},
                                  Destination,                                     # depends on the file name
                                  @{Name = 'Archive'; Expression = {'N/A'}},       # initialize to Not Applicable
                                  Result
        # depending on its name, get the correct destination folder
        $destFolder = if($_.Name -match "Retail-EIP") { $RetailDest } else { $GroupDest }
        # create the backup destination folder if it didn't already exist
        # the first file in column 'Source' is now responsible for creating the backup folder
        $null = New-Item -Path $destFolder -ItemType Directory -Force
        # get the full path and filename for the destination
        $existingFile = Join-Path -Path $destFolder -ChildPath $_.Name -PathType Leaf
        # add the destination folder to the output object
        $out.Destination = $destFolder
        try {
            # if a file with that name already exists in the destination, move it to the Archive folder
            if (Test-Path -Path $existingFile -PathType Leaf) {
                # create the Archive folder if it didn't already exist
                $null = New-Item -Path $ArchiveData -ItemType Directory -Force
                Move-Item -Path $existingFile -Destination $ArchiveData -ErrorAction Stop -WhatIf
                # add the archived file to the output object
                $out.Archive = $existingFile
                Write-Host "File '$existingFile' has been backed-up to '$ArchiveData'"
            }
            # next move the file from the source folder to its destination (either $RetailDest or $GroupDest)
            $_ | Move-Item -Destination $destFolder -ErrorAction Stop -WhatIf
            $out.Result = 'OK'
            Write-Host "File '$($_.FullName)' has been moved to '$destFolder'"
        }
        catch {
            # ouch.. something went horribly wrong on a Move-Item action
            Write-Warning "An error occurred: $_.Exception.Message"
            $out.Result = "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }

        # output the object so it gets collected in variable $result
        $out
    }

# now you can save the results as structured CSV file to open in Excel
$result | Export-Csv -Path $LogFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation -Append

# and display on screen using Out-GridView as the data will probably be too wide for Format-Table
$result | Out-GridView -Title 'Backup results'
```

Please note that I have added a `-WhatIf` switch to the Move-Item cmdlets. This is a safety measure and with that switch, you will only see a line in the console telling you what action *would* be performed. Nothing actually gets moved.
Once you are satisfied with all console messages that everything does what is expected, you can remove these `-WhatIf` switches.

Please read the code comments that (hopefully) explain every step of the way

---

This is taking too long...

What is in the export is what is collected in the objects returned:

| Column | Description |
| --- | --- |
| **Date** | The current date when the file was being processed |
| **Source** | The full path and filename of the file that is being processed from the Source folder |
| **FileSize** | The size in bytes of the file that is being processed |
| **Destination** | The full path of the **destination folder** the source file is moved to, either from `$RetailDest` or `$GroupDest` |
| **Archive** | Either 'N/A' or the full path and filename of the file that was already in the destination folder and had to be moved to the archive folder first |
| **Result** | Either 'OK' or the exception message if something went wrong with `Move-Item` |

Because of `-Include '*Group-EIP*', '*Retail-EIP*'`, only files that have one or the other string in their file Name will be processed, all other files are ignored. That is why you never got exception messages about those wrong files you have tried.. (following note **1** in my answer)

Comment: Hi Theo, Thank you so much for looking into this and giving your valuable time on this. As it worked as expected, one more thing if you can take a look.

Comment: 1. Source is not capturing in logs CSV. 2nd Is there a way to create a backup copy with filename so it would be easy to track because it's not capturing the backup logs in CSV, like which file has created a backup location.

Comment: One more thing, It is overwriting logs so there is only current copy logs only

Comment: @essexlake Please see the edited code. Now, destination folders and the Archive folder only get created when a file needs to be moved there. In the output, the file responsible is always the first file that has the destination mentioned. I have also added switch `-Append` to the Export-Csv, so now the results are added to an already existing file. I have no idea what you mean by _"Source is not capturing in logs CSV"_ though.. It is always the second column in the output..

Comment: What I mean by the source is, there is no data in CSV in Source column.

Comment: @essexlake Aaaaaaaaaaaah.. of course, should have been `$out = $_ | Select-Object ..`

Comment: How can I produce the error logs, like I tried to upload wrong files which not match with file naming convention but it didn't produce the error?

Comment: Date Source FileSize Destination Archive Result
5/18/2021 15:11  0 C:\uploadtool\Retail-EIP.txt D:\ToolUpload\Retail-EIP\Retail-EIP.txt OK,   You can see above logs data which shows source location in Destination Column and Destination location shows in the Archive column.

Comment: Hi Theo, I don't have enough words to thank you. I really appreciate your help. You are the gemstone. Just one more question, if I need to move files from the different-2 source, what should I need to do, like have two sources now Retail-EIP and Group-EIP, and wants to move to compare file to a specific destination.

Comment: @essexlake That's what the code does now. Depending on the file name, it decides to which destination it should go. If there are more destinations, you need to add these to `$destFolder = if($_.Name -match "Retail-EIP") { $RetailDest } else { $GroupDest }`. What is returned in the objects now should be regarded as example. You're free of course to add more properties if you need them.

Comment: Hi Theo, Thanks.  I marked this as solved and you helped a lot. I am really thankful to you. Well my question was if there are multiple sources then how could go with that, what I thought if I merge all destination with join-path and check with if condition.

Comment: Hi Theo, I have accepted this as an answer and thanks a lot to help me. I would say you are the champ.

Comment: Hi Theo, I am sorry to adding a comment here, just small help needed. Please let me know if I need to ask with a new question.