# Can someone help to add email function correctly

Tags: powershell

I am adding an email function to send an email if the file uploads success or failure, but when I upload the file, it sends a message as I write in the body for success but I am not sure if it captures the error function as well in the email.

1. I upload the file as per the naming convention and it moved successfully.
2. When I tried to upload the wrong file through this, it does not capture the catch statement in the log file.
3. I want to capture the backup copy name in logs as well.
4. Got an email on the successful event but didn't get an email on the catch statement.

Please see the below code.

```
$Source      = 'c:\uploadtool\' # Source Location
$RetailSource  = 'Retail P&C Sales Intelligence\*'
$GroupSource = 'Group P&C Sales Intelligence\*'         
$RetailDest  = 'D:\ToolUpload\Retail-EIP'    # 1st Destination Location
$GroupDest   = 'D:\ToolUpload\Group-EIP'     # 2nd Destination location
$ArchiveData = 'D:\Backup\backup_{0:yyyyMMddHHmm}' -f (Get-Date)
$LogFolder   = 'D:\logs'
# because of your wish to get a Table-style log, use CSV format you can open in Excel
$LogFile     = 'D:\logs\uploadlog_{0:yyyyMMdd}.csv'-f (Get-Date)
$Sourcetest = Test-Path -Path '$RetailSource','$GroupSource'  -PathType Leaf
$SmtpServer ='essexlake1.mail.protection.outlook.com' # SMTP Server name
$SmtpPort='25'
$Subject='File Upload Status'
$To="###@domain.com"
$From="####@domain.com"

# make sure the output LogFolder exist
# by adding the -Force switch there is no need to use Test-Path first, because if
# the folder already exists, the cmdlet will return the DirectoryInfo of that,
# otherwise it will create a new folder. Since we dont want output, we use $null = ..
$null = New-Item -Path $LogFolder -ItemType Directory -Force

# loop through the files in the source folder and collect the outputted objects
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path $Sourcetest -Include '*Group-EIP*', '*Retail-EIP*' -File -Force -Recurse | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Processing file '$($_.FullName)'"
        # create an object with (for now) 3 empty properties
        $out = $_ | Select-Object @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {(Get-Date)}},
                                  @{Name = 'Source'; Expression = {$_.FullName}},
                                  @{Name = 'FileSize'; Expression = {$_.Length}},
                                  Destination,                                     # depends on the file name
                                  @{Name = 'Archive'; Expression = {$ArchiveData}},       # initialize to Not Applicable
                                  Result
        # depending on its name, get the correct destination folder
        $destFolder = if($_.Name -match "Retail-EIP") { $RetailDest } else { $GroupDest }
        # create the backup destination folder if it didn't already exist
        # the first file in column 'Source' is now responsible for creating the backup folder
        $null = New-Item -Path $destFolder -ItemType Directory -Force
        # get the full path and filename for the destination
        $existingFile = Join-Path -Path $destFolder -ChildPath $_.Name 
        # add the destination folder to the output object
        $out.Destination = $destFolder
        try {
            # if a file with that name already exists in the destination, move it to the Archive folder
            if (Test-Path -Path $existingFile -PathType Leaf) {
                # create the Archive folder if it didn't already exist
                $null = New-Item -Path $ArchiveData -ItemType Directory -Force
                Move-Item -Path $existingFile -Destination $ArchiveData -ErrorAction Stop 
                # add the archived file to the output object
                $out.Archive = $existingFile
                Write-Host "File '$existingFile' has been backed-up to '$ArchiveData'"
            }
            # next move the file from the source folder to its destination (either $RetailDest or $GroupDest)
            $_ | Move-Item -Destination $destFolder -ErrorAction Stop 
            $out.Result = 'OK'
            Write-Host "File '$($_.FullName)' has been moved to '$destFolder'"
            $Body=" The File '$($_.FullName)' has been moved to '$destFolder"
            Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Port $Port -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body 

        }
        catch {
            # ouch.. something went horribly wrong on a Move-Item action
            Write-Warning "An error occurred: $_.Exception.Message"
            $out.Result = "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" | Add-Content -Path $LogFile -Force
        }

        # output the object so it gets collected in variable $result
        $out
    }

# now you can save the results as structured CSV file to open in Excel
$result | Export-Csv -Path $LogFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation -Append

# and display on screen using Out-GridView as the data will probably be too wide for Format-Table
$result | Out-GridView -Title 'Backup results
```

'

Comment: Why not send an email at the very end with the created `$logFile` as attachment? Then you'll have all info in one email instead of a floodload of separate mails per file? You can even opt to convert the `$result` into a nice HTML table and send it like that.  About your item 2. _When I tried to upload the wrong file_ Please see the final remark on my answer of the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67576493/9898643). The catch has nothing to do with files that do not have `Group-EIP` or `Retail-EIP` in their name, because these will simply not go past the `-Include` parameter

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to send an email on-error because `Send-MailMessage` is the last statement in the `Try{...}` block.  If anything errors before that the statement `Send-MailMessage` won't run.

If it were me, and from this starting point I'd populate `$Body` respective to the outcome (success/fail) and send the email afterward.  Not only would this send with correct information regardless but avoids having a second `Send-MailMessage` command in the catch block.  Obviously I can't rig up a test of such a big code segment, but it might look something like:

```
$Source       = 'c:\uploadtool\' # Source Location
$RetailSource = 'Retail P&C Sales Intelligence\*'
$GroupSource  = 'Group P&C Sales Intelligence\*'         
$RetailDest   = 'D:\ToolUpload\Retail-EIP'    # 1st Destination Location
$GroupDest    = 'D:\ToolUpload\Group-EIP'     # 2nd Destination location
$ArchiveData  = 'D:\Backup\backup_{0:yyyyMMddHHmm}' -f (Get-Date)
$LogFolder    = 'D:\logs'

# because of your wish to get a Table-style log, use CSV format you can open in Excel
$LogFile     = 'D:\logs\uploadlog_{0:yyyyMMdd}.csv'-f (Get-Date)
$Sourcetest  = Test-Path -Path '$RetailSource','$GroupSource'  -PathType Leaf

#Email Params:
$EmailParams = @{
    SmtpServer ='essexlake1.mail.protection.outlook.com' # SMTP Server name
    Port   ='25'
    Subject    ='File Upload Status'
    To         ="###@domain.com"
    From       ="####@domain.com"
}


# make sure the output LogFolder exist
# by adding the -Force switch there is no need to use Test-Path first, because if
# the folder already exists, the cmdlet will return the DirectoryInfo of that,
# otherwise it will create a new folder. Since we dont want output, we use $null = ..
$null = New-Item -Path $LogFolder -ItemType Directory -Force

# loop through the files in the source folder and collect the outputted objects
$result = 
Get-ChildItem -Path $Sourcetest -Include '*Group-EIP*', '*Retail-EIP*' -File -Force -Recurse | 
ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Processing file '$($_.FullName)'"
    
    # create an object with (for now) 3 empty properties
    $out = $_ | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {(Get-Date)}},
        @{Name = 'Source'; Expression = {$_.FullName}},
        @{Name = 'FileSize'; Expression = {$_.Length}},
        Destination,                                      # depends on the file name
        @{Name = 'Archive'; Expression = {$ArchiveData}}, # initialize to Not Applicable
        Result
    
    # depending on its name, get the correct destination folder
    $destFolder = if($_.Name -match "Retail-EIP") { $RetailDest } else { $GroupDest }
    
    # create the backup destination folder if it didn't already exist
    # the first file in column 'Source' is now responsible for creating the backup folder
    $null = New-Item -Path $destFolder -ItemType Directory -Force
    
    # get the full path and filename for the destination
    $existingFile = Join-Path -Path $destFolder -ChildPath $_.Name 
    
    # add the destination folder to the output object
    $out.Destination = $destFolder
    try 
    {   # if a file with that name already exists in the destination, move it to the Archive folder
        if (Test-Path -Path $existingFile -PathType Leaf) {
            # create the Archive folder if it didn't already exist
            $null = New-Item -Path $ArchiveData -ItemType Directory -Force
            Move-Item -Path $existingFile -Destination $ArchiveData -ErrorAction Stop 
            
            # add the archived file to the output object
            $out.Archive = $existingFile
            Write-Host "File '$existingFile' has been backed-up to '$ArchiveData'"
        }
        
        # next move the file from the source folder to its destination (either $RetailDest or $GroupDest)
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $destFolder -ErrorAction Stop 
        $out.Result = 'OK'
        Write-Host "File '$($_.FullName)' has been moved to '$destFolder'"
        $Body = " The File '$($_.FullName)' has been moved to '$destFolder"
    }
    catch 
    {   # ouch.. something went horribly wrong on a Move-Item action
        $Body = " Error occured trying to move the file '$($_.FullName)' to '$destFolder. `n$($_.Exception.Message)"
        Write-Warning "An error occurred: $_.Exception.Message"
        $out.Result = "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" | Add-Content -Path $LogFile -Force
    }

    Send-MailMessage @EmailParams -Body $Body

    # output the object so it gets collected in variable $result
    $out
}

# now you can save the results as structured CSV file to open in Excel
$result | Export-Csv -Path $LogFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation -Append

# and display on screen using Out-GridView as the data will probably be too wide for Format-Table
$result | Out-GridView -Title 'Backup results'
```

Forgive the reformat, that was for my own readability.  I also added splatting to the email command.  You were setting all those parameter vars early in the script any way...

Note: for all other parts of this question I think the straight forward answer is you have to add the instructions to tell the program what you want it to do.  If you want to log on a specific condition, figure out where that's going to happen and add an `Add-Content` command etc...

Comment: Hi Steven, I tried with added function but I am getting the below error.                                            Send-MailMessage: A parameter cannot be found that matches the parameter name SmtpPort

Comment: Sorry, I corrected that. since I took the hash keys from your original variable names it was wrong, the actual param is "`-Port`". That said if the Port # is 25 you can actually omit it completely.  25 is the default.